# What does "navbar-header" class do in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using `.navbar-header` class of Bootstrap for my navigation bars for quite a while but never bothered to wonder why. I searched online as to why we use it but didn't find any explanation. Can someone explain what is it's purpose?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        Website Name
      </a>
    </div>  
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The navbar-header is mostly an architectural class for Bootstrap navbar. It allocates approximately 150px to the left of the navbar to wrap the navbar-brand and allow the brand name or logo to make use of the entire area on click or hover. But the most useful property of the navbar-header is its responsiveness to 100% width on and after 768px (tablet views). This allows the brand to be centered at the top of the viewport which it is a nicety to have to avoid your responsive menu overlapping your brand when it opens. **EDIT** --> The navbar-brand doesn't respond to 100% width.

But you are right, little it's said about this class in the web, because it doesn't per se execute a function. Most people just either leave it alone, replace it, or use it as a hook (parent) class to target the navbar-brand or any other element they wanted to include within.

Comment: Where did *you* get this information? Bootstrap docs don't seem to explain.

Comment: @HappyHands31Years upon years upon years of experience

Answer (score 1):

I think it doesn't exist in Bootstrap 5.
I have searched it in bootstrap.css, and it was not found

Comment: Maybe elaborate?

Comment: This was used in bootstrap 3. bootstrap 4 and higher are using flexbox to align most of the elements