# positioning input at the middle of navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put an input field in the middle of a nabvar to use as a live filter input. At the right of that input should be a span, which will show the number of matches (it's value is changed using jQuery). 
I started out using the text-align: center CSS property, but, as the span is originally hidden, when showed it displaced the input to the left (making the group input + span centered, which makes a lot of sense, given the CSS rule).

Also, I don't seem to be able to change the input width using CSS (I can do it using the size attribute on the HTML tag).

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-erat">
    <div class = "navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle well-bg" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg fa-fw"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <?php if (isset($livefilter)): ?>
        <div class = "navbar-form navbar-form-center">
            <input type = "text" id = "filter" class = "form-control search-input" placeholder = "Filtro"> 
        <span id = "filter-count"></span> 
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</nav>
```

And here's the corresponding CSS:

```
.navbar-erat {
    background: #EEEAF7 !important;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6C9F5 !important;
}

.navbar-form-center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.search-input {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px !important; //For Safari, etc.
    -moz-border-radius: 50px !important; //For Mozilla, etc.
    border-radius: 50px !important; //CSS3 Feature
}
```

And just in case, the jQuery which operates with them:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#filter').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        $("#filter").keyup(function() {
            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(),
                count = 0;
            $(".info-filter").each(function() {

                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(this).fadeOut();

                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });

            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text(" " + count + " coincidencias encontradas");
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, recapitulating I have two main issues:

- Stop the input from moving when the span appears (fixing it somehow to the middle of the navbar)
- Setting the input width from CSS

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `<br/>` right here

```
  <input type="text" id="filter" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Filtro">
  <br>
  <span id="filter-count"></span>`
```

See fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/17/

Answer (score 0):

There were some architectural discrepancies with your Bootstrap structure.

First of all the Bootstrap document provides code snippets to use as guidance but it doesn't mean you have to use everything. So, the `.navbar-header` class expands to 100% occupying your top header and pushing your input field down to the next level. This class is to be removed if you are not interested on placing your logo at the top-center of your mobile version (app-like look) See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689014/what-does-navbar-header-class-do-in-bootstrap/34689095#34689095)

Second, the form control is always 100%, that's good, so you use `col-*` classes to direct the parent size and you keep responsiveness that way.

Third, the `navbar-form` comes with a gutter padding, remove if not needed. That was pretty much the only CSS I had to do.

See my HTML (re-worked)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-erat">
    <div class="">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle well-bg" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body">
            <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg fa-fw"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <?php if (isset($livefilter)): ?>
        <div class="navbar-form col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-5">
            <input type="text" id="filter" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Filtro">
            <span id="filter-count"></span>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</nav>
```

CSS adition

```
    .navbar-form{padding:0;}
```

See the [**demo**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/wMPJYx)

Comment: Thanks for the superb explanation!! This is (almost) what I wanted. If you don't mind, I'd like to ask you a few questions about the code to make the last changes myself (and learn in the process). (1) I'd like the input to be wider, I could do it setting the size attribute of the `<input>` tag, but I wanted to do it using a CSS rule. Now the size att doesn't work. (2) I'm kinda new to Bootstrap. Could you elaborate a bit about the multiple `col-*` classes asigned to the div? I always use 1 `col-XX-#` and one `col-XX-offset-#` at most. I don't understand how they work toghether.

Thanks!!

Comment: (3) The input field doesn't seem to be exactly centered, it might be because it's not really centered, just "manually" put in that position. Is this the case? Can it be "really" centered somehow??

Thanks and sorry to bother you further!

Comment: Thank you. My goal is for you to learn, hence the long explanation. Ok, so I'll try to fit it here. Like I said, the input uses a form-control class that is set to 100% (for a reason). DO NOT ALTER THIS. Instead you use the parent class for sizing. If possible use one of the classes already built for you (the col-* classes). Bootstrap spans across the screen in 12 parts. So if you use col-xs-1 it will be 1/12th of the container's width. if you use col-xs-2 is 2/12th or 1/6th. Which means you can fit 6 of them accross the screen. and so forth. (to be continued)

Comment: (continue pt2) in this particular example I used a size col-sm-4 for tablets and up, and col-xs-6 for smartphones. Notice, I didn't have to specify col-md-4 or col-lg-4. That's becasue Bootstrap is a mobile first framework. Meaning you develop from mobile up. By telling it I want that size at sm, it already knows I want that same size at md and lg. Ok. next step is the shift classes. The size classes I specified first are only for sizing but they are by default floated to the left. So in order to move them, I use the -push- (to be continued)

Comment: (continue pt3) the push is calculated by how many 12th parts you want the item to move. Since the size is different in the sm and xs, I had to make the push different as well to keep it centered. So if you think the input is too small still, increase the size, and decrease the -push- by the same amount and you will be set

Comment: Sometimes, because of other CSS rules in your stylesheet, or even Bootstrap's CSS the input field may come with a margin property. If you think you need to move it to the left just a few pixels, use margin-left: +-px to get it right. That's what margin is for. But at least Bootstrap already kinda centered it responsively too

Comment: Understood! I knew about the 12 columns per row, but I didn't know you could "stack" the xs/sm/md/lg classes to define different widths for different devices (which is, I think, what you are trying to explain me). I tried changing those sizes (for example to 6) but saw no changes in the redered page (doesn't change in the codepen you kindly wrote either). Changing the `push` size does work as expected. Is it maybe a div with class `row` missing as a parent? What's the difference between `push` and `offset`?