# Component is undefined when use react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I have code for react-bootstrap like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavItem, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css'
import NavbarToggle from 'react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarToggle'
import Routes from './Routes'
import NavbarCollapse from 'react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarCollapse'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App container">
      <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <NavbarBrand>
            <Link to="/">Scratch</Link>
          </NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <NavbarCollapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <LinkContainer to="/signup">
              <NavItem>Signup</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/login">
              <NavItem>Sign</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
          </Nav>
        </NavbarCollapse>
      </Navbar>
      <Routes />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

it occurred errors. The errors message are

*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

Note: when I omitted `Navbar.Header` it worked correctly.

Comment: I can't see any mention of `Navbar.Header` in the API docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Comment: Looks like you may be using React Bootstrap 4.5. `Navbar.Header` was removed in this version - https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/migrating/#navbarheader. Look in the list of breaking changes from the previous versions

Comment: so. what should i use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NavBar.Header` was [removed in release v1](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/migrating/#navbar) of React-bootstrap. Basically, if you add this component, it primarily adds to the DOM a `div` with a class of `navbar-header`.

```
<div class="navbar-header"></div>
```

If you are curious to know or want to replicate its behavior, you can take a look at this answer: [What does "navbar-header" class do in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689014/what-does-navbar-header-class-do-in-bootstrap) or take a look at some outdated Bootstrap stylesheet (prior to v4).

If you have the leisure of updating your layout, take a look at the updated examples of React-bootstrap Nav here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars